# How to assign a returned String to an object property in Angular Conroller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a String as a return value in a function in my controller. Like this:

```
        function concatDaysOfWeek() {

        var DaysString = "";

        if (vm.sunday) DaysString = DaysString + '1';
        if (vm.monday) DaysString = DaysString + '2';
        if (vm.tuesday) DaysString = DaysString + '3';
        if (vm.wednesday) DaysString = DaysString + '4';
        if (vm.thursday) DaysString = DaysString + '5';
        if (vm.friday) DaysString = DaysString + '6';
        if (vm.saturday) DaysString = DaysString + '7';

        return DaysString;

    }
```

Now I have an object that needs to be populated with properties.

```
        vm.schedule = {};
```

In my HTML i have created a bunch of ng-model that bind to this object.
But I don't know how to bind the string I get as the return value to a property in my object.

I want something like this:

```
RecurrenceDaysOfWeek: DaysString
```

But it doesn't work. Not inside the object {} nor somewhere else in the controller.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: `vm.schedule = {  xyz : concatDaysOfWeek() };`

Comment: after I did that i see this {"RecurrenceDaysOfWeek":""}. an empty string even though I do select the days. So that did not solve it. I want to see the days change as I select and Unselect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set it in your method?

```
function concatDaysOfWeek() {

    var DaysString = "";
    if (vm.sunday) DaysString = DaysString + '1';
    if (vm.monday) DaysString = DaysString + '2';
    if (vm.tuesday) DaysString = DaysString + '3';
    if (vm.wednesday) DaysString = DaysString + '4';
    if (vm.thursday) DaysString = DaysString + '5';
    if (vm.friday) DaysString = DaysString + '6';
    if (vm.saturday) DaysString = DaysString + '7';

    vm.schedule.myVariable = DaysString;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! this worked. I just had the return of DaysString before the assignment. This was why I was getting the error.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, could you please upvote/select it as the chosen answer so that others viewing the question know? :)

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-init` to call the function and assign value to `ng-model`

```
<input ng-model="vm.schedule.RecurrenceDaysOfWeek" ng-init="vm.schedule.RecurrenceDaysOfWeek = vm.concatDaysOfWeek()"/>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.concatDaysOfWeek = concatDaysOfWeek;
  vm.schedule = {}
  vm.sunday = "1";
   function concatDaysOfWeek() {

        var DaysString = "";

        if (vm.sunday) DaysString = DaysString + '1';
        if (vm.monday) DaysString = DaysString + '2';
        if (vm.tuesday) DaysString = DaysString + '3';
        if (vm.wednesday) DaysString = DaysString + '4';
        if (vm.thursday) DaysString = DaysString + '5';
        if (vm.friday) DaysString = DaysString + '6';
        if (vm.saturday) DaysString = DaysString + '7';

        return DaysString;

    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
 <input ng-model="vm.schedule.RecurrenceDaysOfWeek" ng-init="vm.schedule.RecurrenceDaysOfWeek = vm.concatDaysOfWeek()"/>
</div>
```